# FluentValidation ILanguageManager.GetString() not invoked for custom Rules

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I have a custom rule like this:

```
public static IRuleBuilderOptionsConditions<T, string?> MustBeCool<T>(this IRuleBuilder<T, string?> ruleBuilder)
{
    return ruleBuilder.Custom((input, context) =>
    {
        if(/*input is not cools*/)
        {
            context.AddFailure("Not cool.");
        }
    });
}
```

I also have a custom implementation of the `ILanguageManager` which pulls translations for validation messages from a database. My custom LanguageManager works fine for built-in rules. My problem now is that the `ILanguageManager.GetString(...)` is not getting called for my custom rule. I guessed that this might be because there already is a valiation error message provided so I tried to add the failure like this:

```
context.AddFailure(new ValidationFailure
{
    PropertyName = context.PropertyName,
    ErrorCode = "MustBeCoolValidator"
    // no error message provided
});
```

That doesn't work either. An empty validation error message is returned. In my case the validation rules and the error message translations don't live in the same town so I can't really provide the translated validation error message where the rule is declared.

Is there a way to invoke the `ILanguageManager.GetString()` for my custom rule?

Answer (score -1):

You could pass as parameter because cannot injection in static class.

```
public static IRuleBuilderOptionsConditions<T, string?> 
     MustBeCool<T>(this IRuleBuilder<T, string?> ruleBuilder, ILanguageManager langManager)
{
    return ruleBuilder.Custom((input, context) =>
    {
        if(/*input is not cools*/)
        {
            context.AddFailure(langManager.GetString("NotNullValidator"));
        }
    });
}
```

Usage:

```
public class UserValidation : AbstractValidator<User>
{
    public UserValidation(ILanguageManager languageService)
    {
        RuleFor(p => p.Name).MustBeCool(languageService);
    }

}
```

Dependecy Injection:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ILanguageManager, LanguageManager>();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Okan. Though this would be a solution it seems quite hacky to me. There must be better way to accomplish this.

Comment: I could understand you but you cannot injection in static class. must be passed as a parameter.